# Using cin for keyboard input after processing redirected file input with getline

Tags: c++, cin, getline, io-redirection, istream

I know, this question has been treated tons of times.. but I can't make it work anyway.. here I paste some code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace header;

int main(){
    string parent, child, line, node;
    int choose = 0;
    tree_ptr tree_inst = new tree;
    cout << "*** Start ***" << endl;    
    while (getline(cin, line, '\n')){
        istringstream line_stream(line);
        line_stream >> parent;
        if (parent.compare("0") == 0) break;
        while (line_stream >> child) {
            if (!tree_inst->insert(parent, child)) {
                cout << "*** ERROR! ***" << endl;
                tree_inst->visit(tree_inst->root);
                cout << "*** End ***" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        cin >> choose;  //<== doesn't wait for the input, just loop forever
                        //    on the default statement of the switch...
        switch (choose) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to insert some cin.sync() cin.clear() cin.ignore() ..etc.. but nothing changed!

Comment: PS: "string" and "iostream" are included inside "header.h"..

Comment: What's your input, if it's not anything that can be parsed as an integer the text will not be removed from the input buffer so the next loop the same input will be read again. You need *both* to ignore the rest of the line *and* clear the error. See the example in this [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) reference how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it! anyway the input is a text file (on Linux I use the console to stream the file into the program with "./myprogram < text"), here an example of the input:                                                                            parent child1 child 2 \n                                                                                          parent1 child1 child2 child 3 \n                                                                      ...

Comment: I've just tried: while (true) {

  cin.clear();

  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

  cin >> choose;

  switch (choose) { ... etch...  but nothing changed :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue !   How do you get out of the first loop ?

Comment: At the end of the text file I added zero, then inside the loop there is an if statement that check if line == 0, if true break

Comment: @Moriduri ok, but do you mean "0" or do you mean 0  (ascii null) ?  Can you try the solution and tell the output of the diagnostic lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `getline()` loop would loop forever, if you don't break it in one way or another.  If done in a clean manner, this shouldn't be an issue at all. In fact I could not reproduce your error.

## How to analyze the error

So the cause is either a bad sate of `cin` or non numberic non space input that is still pending.  To help you find out, I suggest you add some diagnostic code:

```
cout << "Enter free lines of text or stop to return to the menu:";
while (getline(cin, line, '\n')) {   // This would loop foreved
    if (line == "stop")              // I added this one to exit
        break;                       // but how do you do ?
}
while (true) {                       // I get no problem here
    cout << "Cin status: failed="    // <===Add this simple diagnostic to 
         << cin.fail() << " bad="    //     check the state of the stream 
         << cin.bad() << " eof=" << cin.eof() << endl;  
    cout << "Next char in decimal is:" // <=== Add this to show 
         << cin.peek() << endl;        //      where in the stream you're hanging
    cout << "Choose:";
    cin >> choose;  
    cout << "selected: " << choose << endl;
}
```

If your stream state is not clean, despite a `cin.clean()` , it's because either you closed the stream or typed in an end-of-file code at the console (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> depending on system) .

It the stream state is clean but  the [peeked](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) char is not numeric (i.e. decimal code not between 48 and 57), it's the bad input that sets the stream in a fail state.

## Edit: your specific case

Looking at the diagnostic you've provided (fail=1, eof=1), it appears that after the first loop you've already eached the end of the input. So your input fails because there is no  further data to read.   Your input file on pastebin confirms that the last line is the "0" that you use to exit the first loop.

Following our exchanges, I understand that you've in fact redirected input from the command line (e.g.  `yourprogramme <yourinput.txt` ) and expect your code to switch back to keyboard input once the redirected file input reaches its end.   Unfortunately this is not the way it works.  If you redirect input from a file, `cin` will always refer to the redireted file.

To be able to mix file and keyboard input, you need to use [`<fstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/) and more precisely `ifstream` for reading from the file and keep `cin` for keyboard entry.

Here is a slightly modified code that takes the filename from the command line but without indirection (e.g. `yourprogramme yourinput.txt` ):

```
...
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {     // if called from command line wrong arguments
        cerr << "You must provide the name of the data file as command line argument\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ifstream file(argv[1]);     // open the file for reading 
    if (!file) {                // if open failed, end the programme
        cerr << "Could not open "<<argv[1]<<"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    string line;                // here your code from before
    int choose = 0;
    cout << "*** Loading "<<argv[1]<< " ***" << endl;
                              // but in the first loop replace cin with file
    while (getline(file, line, '\n')){   
        cout << "Read: " << line<<endl;
        if (line == "0")                // Abridged version;-)
            break;
    }
    file.close();               // File is no longer needed here.  
    while (true) {              // Second loop, unchanged, using cin  
        cout << "Choose (9 to exit):";
        if (!(cin >> choose))   // avoid looping forever if problem on cin
            break;
        cout << "selected: " << choose << endl;
        if (choose == 9)
            break;  
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: the output now is (with the cout and cin.fail cin.bad ...):         Cin status: failed=1 bad=0 eof=1
Next char in decimal is:-1

Comment: @Moriduri this mean that for sure you have reached the end of file.  (eof==1 and peek with -1).  Did you remove the cin.ignore()  of your previous tests ?

Comment: @Moriduri Ok, to summarize, when you leave the first loop, you don't ignore anything, but yet when entering in the second loop you are already at the end of file.  This means that your code to exit the first loop doesn't work as you think and the while is only interupted because you've reached the end of file.   You should edit the question and put the exact code you have to leave the first loop and also show the content of your input file.

Comment: PS: this  http://pastebin.com/mXE8BxUn  is the link to the INPUT file i'm currently using ;)

Comment: @Moriduri ok: the last line of your file is the "0" that will break your first loop.  But there is no line after this: any subsequent attempt to read in the second loop will fail.  Try to add a menu choice to your file and it will work !

Comment: @Moriduri P.S: Looking at your code and the fact that you speak of a file, I understand that you are running your programme by redirecting the input at os level (i.e. `myprog <testfile.txt`).  If you do this, at the end of the file, the programme will not switch back to the keyboard:  the redirection is definitive, so any cin when you've reached the end of file will fail.  If you want to mix file input and keyboard input, you have to explicitely read the file using an  `ifstream` and keep cin for real keyboard input.

Comment: please can you make me an example? I'm a bit confused, thanks.

Comment: @Moriduri I've made an edit showing you in detail how to do this.

Comment: your explanation has been very exhausting, I wanna really thank you for your help and your patience!! thanks!!! :)